Laplace Transform of a Second Order Systems Response to Triangular Pulse

I've been trying to derive the time domain response of a second order system to triangular pulse input using Laplace Transformation but even if I seem to be able to derive it Simulink simulations provide different results than expected. My steps are included below. I double checked the results with Wolfram and can't find where I made a mistake. I would really appricate any help.
Considering a second order system$\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2 + 2\zeta\omega_ns + \omega_n^2}$ and a triangular pulse of slope $k$ and peak point at $t = z$, the Laplace transform can be derived for $w_n = 6$ and $\zeta = 1$:
\begin{equation}
Model * tri(k,z) \Rightarrow
\frac{36}{s^2 + 12s + 36}\cdot\frac{k}{s^2}[1-2e^{-sz}+e^{-2sz}] = \frac{A}{s} + \frac{B}{s^2} + \frac{C}{s+6} + \frac{D}{(s+6)^2} \Rightarrow \\  \frac{-k}{3}\frac{(1-2e^{-sz}+e^{-2sz})}{s} + \frac{k(1-2e^{-sz}+e^{-2sz})}{s^2} + \frac{k}{3} \frac{(1-2e^{-sz}+e^{-2sz})}{s+6} + k\frac{(1-2e^{-sz}+e^{-2sz})}{(s+6)^2}
\end{equation}
Following the derivation, for $t\geqslant0$ inverse Laplace Transform can be calculated as:
\begin{equation}
\small
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Model*tri(k,z)\} = \frac{-k}{3}[u(t) -2u(t-z)+u(t-2z)] + k[r(t) -2r(t-z)H(t-z) +r(t-2z)H(t-2z)] + \frac{k}{3}[e^{-6t}-2e^{-6(t-z)}H(t-z)+e^{-6(t-2z)}H(t-2z)] + k[te^{-6t} - 2((t-z)e^{-6(t-z)}H(t-z) + (t-2z)e^{-6(t-2z)}H(t-2z)]
\end{equation}
Where u(t) is general and H(t) is the heaviside unit step functions.
Where do i make a mistake? I would appricate any help you can provide.
Edit: Modified the corrected solution.

You state that $\zeta=6$, but later you substitute the following value $2\zeta\omega_n=12$, which would imply $\zeta=1$. So which is the correct value for $\zeta$?

Sorry for the typo, corrected it

You have a mistake in one of the coefficients obtained from the partial fraction decomposition.

Found it, thank you so much!
